# ASP.NET Menu Spacing Issue with Drop Down Arrow

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET menu and for the items that contain a drop down menu, it displays an arrow in a new `<td>`, the problem is the spacing is horrible. How do i tap into that `<TD>` or lessen the spacing between the menu text and Arrow?

Screenshot of menu issue: [image]

HTML Output:

```
<td style="white-space:nowrap;">
<a class="ctl00_itemMenu_1 StaticMenuItemStyle ctl00_itemMenu_3" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;" href="Default.aspx">&nbsp;Home&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
</td>
<td style="width:0;">
<img style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" alt="Expand Home" src="Images/menu_arrow.gif">
</td>
```

Menu Control:

```
<asp:Menu ID="itemMenu" SkinID="MenuSkin" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal"
            CssClass="menu" DynamicItemFormatString="&nbsp;{0}&nbsp;&nbsp;" StaticItemFormatString="&nbsp;{0}&nbsp;&nbsp;"
            StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="true" StaticPopOutImageUrl="~/Images/menu_arrow.gif"
            DynamicPopOutImageUrl="~/Images/menu_arrow_dynamic.gif" DynamicEnableDefaultPopOutImage="true" 
            MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="5">
            <StaticMenuStyle CssClass="StaticMenuStyle" />
            <StaticMenuItemStyle Width="100%" CssClass="StaticMenuItemStyle" />
            <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="StaticHoverStyle" />
            <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="DynamicMenuStyle" />
            <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="DynamicMenuItemStyle" Width="100%" />
            <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="DynamicHoverStyle" />
        </asp:Menu>
```

CSS:

```
.menu
{
padding: 0px 0px 0px 7px;
margin:0px;
}

.StaticMenuStyle a, .StaticMenuStyle a:visited, .StaticMenuStyle a:active, .StaticMenuStyle a:hover
{
color: #ffffff;     
text-decoration: none;
padding: 3px 9px 3px 9px;   
height: 100%;               
display: table;     
font-weight: bold;      
font-family: Tahoma, Arial; 
}

 .DynamicMenuStyle a, .DynamicMenuStyle a:visited, .DynamicMenuStyle a:active,    .DynamicMenuStyle a:hover 
{
color: #ffffff;     
text-decoration: none;
padding: 7px 9px 7px 9px;
width: 100%;    
height: 100%;               
display: table;         
font-weight: bold;  
font-family: Tahoma, Arial; 
}

.StaticMenuStyle td
{
font-weight: normal;
height: 100%;
font-size: 11px;
border-collapse: collapse;
/*cursor: pointer;*/    

}

.DynamicMenuStyle table
{
border-collapse: collapse;  
border-spacing: 0px;
}

.DynamicMenuStyle td
{
border: solid 1px #ffffff;  
font-weight: normal;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
/*cursor: pointer;*/    
background-color: #333333;      
border-collapse: collapse;  
border-spacing: 0px;
font-size: 11px;
}

.DynamicMenuStyle td table tr td
{
border: solid 0px #ffffff;
padding: 7px 4px;


    }

.StaticMenuItemStyle td
  { 

padding: 7px 0px 7px 0px;

border: 0px solid #ffffff;
font-weight: normal;        
text-align: left;   
  }


.StaticHoverStyle td, .DynamicHoverStyle td
{
background-color: #5c5c5c;
font-weight: bold;  
}

.StaticSelectedStyle, .DynamicSelectedStyle
{
font-weight: normal;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code for the css class "menu". One other thing, you can insert images directly into your post. Just hit the image icon on the toolbar, it works better than linking to a separate webpage and images uploaded through any SE site lasts longer than a regular imgur upload.

Comment: Try adding `text-align:right;` in the style for `StaticMenuStyle`

Comment: Tried "text-align:right;", but it didn't change anything :(

Comment: It might have something to do with the two `&nbsp;` you have trailing the text in the Dynamic/Static ItemFormatString.

Comment: removed the &nbsp; from the ItemFormatString, but it didnt remove the spacing between the text and arrow.

Comment: Has anyone come up with an answer to this question? any solution from the OP?